# Azure Pipelines YAML parameter inside parameter name (dynamic parameter name)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a YAML template with parameters:

```
  - name: Deploy_Test1
    type: boolean
    default: false
  - name: Tests
    type: object
    default:
      - "Test1"
      - "Test2"
```

After that I iterate the `Tests` with `each`:

```
- ${{ each test in parameters.Tests}}:
```

Inside the `each` I can get the `test` value with `${{test}}`.

I want to use the parameter `Deploy_Test1` but dynamically, for example:

```
echo ${{ parameters.Deploy_${{test}} }}
```

In the above syntax I get an error that is invalid.

Is there is a way or a workaround to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use two loops here and check if you find your key.

```yaml
parameters:
- name: Deploy_Test1
  type: boolean
  default: false
- name: Tests
  type: object
  default:
    - "Test1"
    - "Test2"

trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- ${{ each test in parameters.Tests}}:
  - ${{ each parameter in parameters }}:
    - ${{ if eq(parameter.key, format('Deploy_{0}', test)) }}:
      - script: echo ${{ parameter.value }}
```

And then you will get:

[image]